# Finding a conformal map to the upper half-plane

Tags: complex-analysis, conformal-geometry

Find a conformal map from the set $$\{z \in \mathbb{C}: |\operatorname{Im}z| < \pi \}\setminus \left[-\pi i; 0 \right]$$ to the upper half-plane.
I have used a composition of the following maps: $$z \mapsto e^{z},\space z \mapsto \frac{1}{z + 1}, \space z \mapsto z - \frac{1}{2}$$
Hence I have got the set $$\mathbb{C}\setminus\left(\left(-\infty; -\frac{1}{2} \right]\cup\left[\frac{1}{2};+\infty \right) \cup\left[0; \infty·i \right]\right)$$
But I'm wondering what the next steps are.

Comment: I would advise that after the exponential, you take a square root (so you'd get $z \mapsto e^{z/2}$). Then you can map what you got to a "disk minus a radius". I think going from a disk minus a radius to a half-plane is easier to see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let \begin{align}
\varphi &: z \mapsto \exp\left(\frac{\,z\,}{2}\right),\\
\psi &: z\mapsto i\frac{z-1}{z+1},\\
\phi &: z \mapsto \sqrt{z},\\
g &: z \mapsto \left(\frac{1+z}{1-z}\right)^2,
\end{align}
where $\sqrt{z}$ is defined in $\mathbb{C}\setminus [0,\infty)$ so that $\sqrt{re^{i\theta }}=\sqrt{r}e^{i\theta /2} $ for $0<\theta <2\pi$.
Also we define
\begin{align}
D&=\{z\in \mathbb{C} : |\operatorname{Im}\, z|<\pi\}\setminus [-\pi i; 0],\\
D_1&=\{z\in \mathbb{C} : \operatorname{Re}\, z>0\}\setminus \left\{z : z=e^{i\theta}, -\frac{\pi}{2}<\theta \le 0\right\},\\
D_2&=\{z\in \mathbb{C} : |z|<1\} \setminus [0; 1),\\
D_3&=\{z\in \mathbb{C} :\operatorname{Im}\,z>0, |z|<1\}.
\end{align}

Note that 
\begin{align}
&\varphi : D\to D_1,\quad \psi : D_1\to D_2, \quad \phi : D_2\to D_3,\\
&g : D_3\to \mathbb{H}, 
\end{align}
where $\mathbb{H}$ is the upper half-plane. See the diagram below.
Thus we get $$
f(z)=g\circ\phi\circ\psi\circ\varphi (z)=\left(\frac{1+\sqrt{i\frac{e^\frac{z}{2}-1}{e^\frac{z}{2}+1}}}{1-\sqrt{i\frac{e^\frac{z}{2}-1}{e^\frac{z}{2}+1}}}\right)^2
$$
as a desired mapping function.
[image]